# TensorFlow - GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to save and restore a tensorflow model and I get the infamous `ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB`.

I was under the belief that my problem has something to do with unnecessary data (I only need the variables), so I tried fixing the issue by handing a dict of variables to the saver.

Unfortunately I still get the 2G error. the overlay.meta file is  ~325 MB.

Any ideas?

**code for model definition, session running and saving:**

```
batch_size = 16
patch_size = 5
depth = 16
num_hidden = 64
num_channels = 1
num_labels = 2
image_size = 64
lim_valid_test = 1000 

# Input data.
tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size, image_size, num_channels))
tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset[:lim_valid_test])
tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

# Variables.
layer1_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([patch_size, patch_size, num_channels, depth], stddev=0.1), name='layer1_weights')
layer1_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([depth]), name='layer1_biases')
layer2_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([patch_size, patch_size, depth, depth], stddev=0.1), name='layer2_weights')
layer2_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[depth]), name='layer2_biases')
layer3_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([image_size // 4 * image_size // 4 * depth, num_hidden], stddev=0.1), name='layer3_weights')
layer3_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_hidden]), name='layer3_biases')
layer4_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden, num_labels], stddev=0.1), name='layer4_weights')
layer4_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_labels]), name='layer4_biases')

# Model.
def model(data):
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(data, layer1_weights, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer1_biases)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(hidden, layer2_weights, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer2_biases)
    shape = hidden.get_shape().as_list()
    reshape = tf.reshape(hidden, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, layer3_weights) + layer3_biases)
    return tf.matmul(hidden, layer4_weights) + layer4_biases

# Training computation.
logits = model(tf_train_dataset)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=tf_train_labels))

# Optimizer.
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)

# Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_valid_dataset))
test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_test_dataset))

# init saver
g_vars = {'layer1_weights':layer1_weights, 'layer1_biases':layer1_biases,
          'layer2_weights':layer2_weights, 'layer2_biases':layer2_biases,
          'layer3_weights':layer3_weights, 'layer3_biases':layer3_biases, 
          'layer4_weights':layer4_weights, 'layer4_biases':layer4_biases
          }
saver = tf.train.Saver(g_vars) 

num_steps = 10000




with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print('variables initialized')
    for step in range(num_steps):
        offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
        batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :, :, :]
        batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
        _, l, predictions = sess.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        if (step % 50 == 0):
            print('Minibatch loss at step %d: %f' % (step, l))
            print('Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
            print('Validation accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels[:lim_valid_test]))
    print('Test accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
    print('saving trained model')
    savePath = saver.save(sess, 'overlay', global_step=1000)
    print ('saved')

num_steps = 10000

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print('variables initialized')
    for step in range(num_steps):
        offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
        batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :, :, :]
        batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
        _, l, predictions = sess.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        if (step % 50 == 0):
            print('Minibatch loss at step %d: %f' % (step, l))
            print('Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
            print('Validation accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels[:lim_valid_test]))
    print('Test accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
    print('saving trained model')
    savePath = saver.save(sess, 'overlay', global_step=1000)
    print ('saved')
```

Comment: what's your size of `valid_dataset` and `test_dataset` ?

Comment: both are around (30000,64,64,1)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try these things:

1. Avoids tf.Constant() of big size, because tf.Constant will be stored as a Node in Graph,and all constant values will be packed into GrapDef proto. In your code, i guess

   ```
   tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset[:lim_valid_test])
   tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)
   ```

   should be avoided and replaced with placeholder
2. If (1) is still not working, you can try following codes to see which operation causes that error:

   ```
   graph = tf.get_default_graph()
   graph.as_graph_def().ByteSize()   # see whole bytes of GraphDef
   graph.as_graph_def()              # see nodeDef, especially notices large `attr.value.tensor_content`
   ```